# AJAX settings in IIS 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, .net-4.0

For my test, I have two different machines with Windows 7. On both machines is IIS 7 installed and activated. I have configured both machines like the other and on both machines I load the same project. The whole project runs nice on both machines, but the UpdatePanel don't work in one machine.

Are there any settings for the AJAX-function in the IIS 7? Have I to add tags to the Web.config file?

Ask if anything isn't clear.

Comment: can you give more specific issues? do you see the error in the event viewer?  Examples re like  following   http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2007/03/28/110161.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/p/1361139/4235931.aspx

Comment: what is the exception

Comment: Which browser are you using? What does the Network tab in the developer tools show as the result of the UpdatePanel AJAX request?

Comment: I use IE 9, but it HAVE TO run on the IE 9. The ISS runs on a administrator account. And now, I see, I have an error in my Console: "SCRIPT5022: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load."

Comment: Now, what I have to do? On Google you find only problems.

Comment: Now, i have solved the problem. I have add an handler from the framework 4.0 in 64bit to *.axd and *.asmx, and now it works. Thank you for your help!